# In-App Purchase for uploading content to server from app

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase

I am working on an app that basically allow user to upload some videos and docs. Client wants to add payment for uploading contents. Like if user upload 10 photos, its free but for more than 10 user has to pay some charges say 5$ for next photos.

I just want to know that can i use the third party payment options like PayPal or similar or i must use the In-App purchase for it.

I gone through the apple guidelines but nothing mentioned for uploading content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the review guidelines cover your situation pretty clearly:

> 11.1
>   Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

Check them out here: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies

Comment: Ok, so it means that if application allow user to upload digital content on server and for which they have to pay, then in this case we should implement iAP, correct?